# Help with dirt-simple led array

Tags: led, usb

I am making a real simple 8x8 led array (each in parallel).
[image: led array]

According to this, can I just skip the resistor?
Also, I have a usb charging port capable of 2.1A 5v. Can I just use the generic usb cable to  bus the power? Is there any problem that you can see? (last thing I want is burning out some thing)

Answer (score 2):

You require a resistor for each LED.  The LEDs are not guaranteed to have identical characteristics so, if you connect them all in parallel, with a single current-limiting resistor, some LEDs will draw more current, and be brighter (and burn out sooner) than others.

Are you sure that the 30 mA/LED you show in your calculations is the recommended operating current, and not the Absolute Maximum current, beyond which the LEDs may be damaged?  You should never operate an LED (or anything, for that matter) at the Absolute Maximum rating.

Comment: the spec does not state abs max current. However, the max peak forward current is listed as 75mA. 30mA is just listed as forward current

Comment: +1. Each series chain of LEDs should have its own current limiting. As all the diodes are in parallel this means you will need one per LED.

Comment: Isn't 30mA listed as max value of forward current, where 75mA is just value of max peak forward current? Nonetheless, just as everyone has already said - you need those resistors.

Answer (score 0):

Should work OK, but leave the resistor in place!  I would go about 20mA (assuming a generic LED), and thus ~1.5 ohms.  Three 1 ohm resistors, two in parallel with one in series should do the trick 
               +---[===]---+
Vin---[===]----+           +---Vout
               +---[===]---+
where - and + are wires, and [===] is a 1 ohm resistor.
The resistors will drop 1.8V at 1.3A though, so you'll probably want 5W resistors, 2W minimum.  Make sure that 30mA is actually the operating current, NOT the absolute maximum.  If so, then your calculations are correct, but I'd bet that it's 20mA continuous.  If it's 30, then you can use a 1 ohm resistor.

Comment: No. No. No. Paralleling 64 LEDs is a ferociously bad idea.

Comment: Specifically: due to manufacturing irregularities, not all of your LEDs will have the same Vf. The LED with the lowest Vf will end up taking the bulk of the current intended for all 64 LEDs, and will burn out. The process will continue with the LED with the next highest Vf, and so on until your whole array is dead.

Comment: @duskwulf I've seen it done successfully too many times, to hold with that line.  measure the V vs I curve of an ordinary LED between 10 and 30 mA, note that it's upwards all the way.

Comment: Never said it was a good idea, just that it'd work. I'm assuming they're all the same type of LED.  I wouldn't do it that way, but the whole manufacturing tolerances thing is unlikely to cause a huge issue here.  Running them at 30mA, the absolute max would be asking for trouble, but at 20, you should be fine even if some draw a little extra.

Answer (score 0):

Paralleling LEDS usually works if they are all of the same type.(especially for small LEDs) but you need that resistor, either use resistive cable or a discrete part.